# Vue Router Parameter Object Type Change On Browser Back Button

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am passing a parameter forum, which is an Object to a route in Vue.js (using vue-router)

```
  {
    path: '/forum/:forum',
    name: 'ForumView',
    component: ForumView,
    props: true
  }
```

When i leave that specific forum route by using another link( to something like forum/post) on the page and after that try to go back to the form page using the back button in the browser I get the following error in the console

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "forum". Expected Object, got String with value "[object Object]".
```

So the router passes the javscript object when using the router link. But when using the back button of the browser (accessing the history), the object is converted into a string.

Curious if there is a fix for that or if I can't / shouldn't pass objects as parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"But when using the back button of the browser (accessing the history), the object is converted into a string"

...this is not entirely correct. The object is converted to a string much sooner - at the time you are navigating to your `forum` route to be precise. When you use back button, there is no object at all. There is only URL with dynamic `:forum` segment replaced by the text "[object Object]" (just check browser's URL bar)

This is the problem when passing objects through the router. Because even if you use `Router` in history mode and the browser's `history` API is used behind the scenes, router doesn't store any parameters when calling `history.pushState`. It pushes only URL. So if you really need something to pass to a target component, that information should by encoded in the URL (route definition) in the form of dynamic segment or as query string...

Another benefit of such solution is that your app doesn't stop working when user copy/paste the URLs :)

Or you can use something like `Vuex` to create shared state and only pass around some simple identifier which is much easier to put in the url/route...